# How to AddRange many lists of IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> into IEnumerable<List<int>>

Tags: c#, casting, enumerable

I have those functions

```
    public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> GetPermutations<T>(IEnumerable<T> items, int count)
    {
        int i = 0;
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            if (count == 1)
                yield return new T[] { item };
            else
            {
                foreach (var result in GetPermutations(items.Skip(i + 1), count - 1))
                    yield return new T[] { item }.Concat(result);
            }

            ++i;
        }
    }

    public static List<List<int>> GetAllValidCombinations(List<int> items)
    {
        var finalList = new List<List<int>>();
        switch (items.Count)
        {
            case 1:
                finalList.Add(items);
                break;
            case 3:
                finalList.AddRange(GetPermutations(items, 2));
                finalList.AddRange((List<List<int>>)GetPermutations(items, 3));
                break;
        }
        return finalList;
    }
```

and i want to get an List<List> from **GetAllValidCombinations**.

In the case 3 of **GetAllValidCombinations**in the first line im getting:
Error   CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Collections.Generic.List>'

and if i try the second line im getting error Specified cast is not valid

How i can do this cast in one line?

Comment: `finalList.AddRange(GetPermutations(items, 2).Select(x => x.ToList()));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sweepers answer is on the money, also you could refactor it a little by only using lists in the inner collection and making it completely generic.

```
public static IEnumerable<List<T>> GetPermutations<T>(List<T> items, int count)
{
   for (var index = 0; index < items.Count; index++)
      if (count == 1)
         yield return new List<T> { items[index] };
      else
         foreach (var result in GetPermutations(items.Skip(index + 1).ToList(), count - 1))
            yield return new List<T> { items[index] }
               .Concat(result)
               .ToList();
}

public static IEnumerable<List<T>> GetAllValidCombinations<T>(List<T> items)
{
   if (items.Count == 1)
       return new List<List<T>> {items};

   if (items.Count == 3)
      return GetPermutations(items, 2)
         .Concat(GetPermutations(items, 3));

   return Enumerable.Empty<List<T>>();
}
```

**Usage**

```
var results = GetAllValidCombinations(new List<int>() {1, 2, 3});

foreach (var result in results)
   Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",",result));
```

**Output**

```
1,2
1,3
2,3
1,2,3
```

[**Full Demo Here**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/FS9B3L)

Comment: Hi @CDrosos are you saying that it doesn't behave as expected, or there is an error ?

Comment: i want GetPermutations(items, 2) to provide a List<int> and GetPermutations(items, 3) to provide another List<int> and both of them to be on another List that GetAllValidCombinations will return. With your implementation i think the returned list will have only one list

Comment: @CDrosos ahh yes i see what you are saying

Comment: @CDrosos  however it does as you would expect. Its joining the 2 collections of collections and returning them in a collection of collections. which is the same as creating a collection and 2 AddRanges and returning the result

Comment: but your implementation will return GetAllValidCombinations(somethin).Count == 1 while i want GetAllValidCombinations(somethin).Count == 2. i want the GetPermutations results in seperated lists

Comment: @CDrosos test https://dotnetfiddle.net/ldLBuR, is this not doing what you want?

Comment: Nice site i didn't know that. Yes your code indeed returns what i want. although i cant understand how for now. May i ask something else. is your implementation faster than Sweeper's answer. My code will do many calculations and i would like the faster approach

Comment: @CDrosos they would be almost identical in allocations and speed from what i can tell

Answer (score 2):

`AddRange` expects an `IEnumerable` of `List`s, but you have given it an `IEnumerable` of `IEnumerable`s. Those `IEnumerable` could be anything, not necessarily lists, right? They could be sets or arrays or some other type that I wrote, that just happens to implement `IEnumerable<T>`... This is the reason why the compiler gives you the error.

And as you have written `GetPermutations`, we can see that they are actually arrays of `T`! So you are trying to add a bunch of arrays to a list of lists! That doesn't make much sense, does it?

Fortunately, `ToList` converts any `IEnumerable` to a `List`. You should apply this method to each `IEnumerable` nested inside the outer `IEnumerable` using `Select`:

```
var enumerableOfEnumerables = GetPermutations(items, 2);
finalList.AddRange(enumerableOfEnumerables.Select(x => x.ToList()));
```

Comment: You are right, i knew that what i was doing doesn't make sense without some casting but i wasn't able to figure out an one line cast for some reason, thanks